# Regular expression for finding images

Tags: regex, expression

I'm in need of regular expression help.

Basically I have this regular expression:

```
src="([^"]+)"
```

I need to improve it so that it only finds images that don't have an absolute pathname, i.e:
http://website.com/folder/image.jpg

I need it so it only lists images with image.jpg and a regular expression that will list ones with a the absolute path.

I was messing around and tried something like this:

```
src=.*http\:.+"([^"]+)"
```

but it didn't work...

Comment: you could use XPath / css selector query to grab the img link

Comment: In R, make sure that you use ' to open/close strings which contain a " unless you use the \ escape character.

Comment: src=".*http\://([^"]+)" - regex works to find links with images, just need one that will find images without links images.jpg, file1.jpg etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general regex to get ones with just image names might be

```
 # \ssrc\s*=\s*"([^/"]+\.(?:jpg|gif|<whatever>))\s*"

 \s 
 src
 \s* = \s* 
 "
 (                                  # (1 start)
      [^/"]+ 
      \. 
      (?: jpg | gif | <whatever> )
 )                                  # (1 end)
 \s* 
 "
```

**Edit** - Without specific file extension

```
 # \ssrc\s*=\s*"([^/"]+\.[^/".]+"

 \s 
 src
 \s* = \s* 
 "
 (                                  # (1 start)
      [^/"]+ 
      \. 
      [^/".]+
 )                                  # (1 end)
 "
```

Comment: Works, is it possible to do without specifying the file extension though?

Comment: @dsme - Sure, just added it.